# Bootstrap timepicker gets NaN while increasing or decreasing both hours and minutes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, momentjs, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I'm trying to figure why this `uib-datepicker` always displays `NaN` while increasing or decreasing both hours and minutes.

```
    <uib-timepicker ng-model="aliasCtrl.beginning"
                    hour-step="hStep"
                    minute-step="mStep"
                    readonly-input="false"
                    show-meridian="ismeridian"></uib-timepicker>
```

which is linked with the following controller:

```
angular.module('app')
  .controller(
    'newController', ['$http', '$uibModalInstance', 'params', function($http, $uibModalInstance, params) {

      var rootScope = this;

      rootScope.begin= params.beg.format('hh:mm');

      rootScope.beginning = new Date();
      rootScope.beginning.setHours(parseInt(this.begin.split(':')[0]));
      rootScope.beginning.setMinutes(parseInt(this.begin.split(':')[1]));
      ...
```

before any interaction with datepicker it displays precompiled values... `params.beg` is a `Moment`.

Comment: Try creating a date object, and set the hours and minutes to it, then set the date object to `rootScope.beginning` (`var a=new Date();a.setHours(...);rootScope.beginning=a;`)

Comment: Forgive my ignorance in JavaScript but I did what you've wrote but something like this could be the same? `var aDate = new Date(); aDate.setHours(parseInt(this.inizio.split(':')[0])); aDate.setMinutes(parseInt(this.inizio.split(':')[1]));  rootScope.dataInizio = aDate;` whatever, it doesn't work. Same NaN as before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just forgot to put the `aliasCtrl.` at the beginning of both `hStep` and `mStep` and this meant that the timepicker didn't know how much to increase or decrease hours and minutes.

It should be something like:

```
 <uib-timepicker ng-model="aliasCtrl.beginning"
                hour-step="aliasCtrl.hStep"
                minute-step="aliasCtrl.mStep"
                readonly-input="false"
                show-meridian="aliasCtrl.ismeridian"></uib-timepicker>
```

because in my controller I had also `rootScope.hstep = 1;`, `rootScope.mstep = 30;` and `rootScope.ismeridian = false;`

I didn't figured at once.